# Factory class should be singleton or static method?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, naming

I made a class which create various instance. It's like a factory.
As i know the factory class is singleton or create instance as static method.
but my class is spring prototype scope. it has member variable. also there  are methods have to call on sequence
set member variable after each methods call.

I want to know in this case how does it design.
could you recommend better way or good naming?

I’m working on spring framework and java 8..

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class FruiteFactory {

    private String type;
    @Setter
    private Integer field;  // set alfter call appleSupplier

    public FruiteFactory(String type) {
        Assert.notNull(type) ;
        this .type = type ;
    }

    public < T> T create(Class<T > clazz) {
        Object result;
        if (clazz == Apple.class) {
            result = appleSupplier.get();
        } else if (clazz == Banana. class) {
            result = bananaSupplier.get();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return (T ) result;
    }

    private Supplier<Apple> appleSupplier = () -> {
        Apple apple = new Apple();
        // ...
        return apple;
    };

    private Supplier<Banana> bananaSupplier = () -> {
        Banana banana = new Banana();
        banana.setField(field);
        return banana;
    };
}


@Service
public class FruiteService {
    @Autowired ApplicationContext context;

    public void buy(String type) {
        FruiteFactory fruiteFactory = context.getBean(FruiteFactory.class, type);

        Apple apple = fruiteFactory.create(Apple.class);
        // save the apple

        Integer no = apple.getNo();
        fruiteFactory.setField(no);

        Banana banana = fruiteFactory.create(Banana.class);
        // ....

    }
}
```

Comment: The factory pattern never imposes the factory to be a singleton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to create fruits from their class name (which I would not advice in the general case), you should just use a `Map<Class<?>, Supplier<?>>` and then use `Class.cast` to return the correct type.

Also, it sounds terribly wrong that your factory includes a field only used for creating apples. This field should definitely be enclosed by whatever is the `Supplier` of apples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Actually the “FruiteFactory" has more supplier(cherry, melon, peach...) and more member variable what they are related each others. so proposed by you Map can not use it. Could you suggest for me specific any way?

Comment: The more suppliers you will have, the more relevant will be the map

Comment: for example.
set field1 any value after creating apple.
and when create banana have to refer as field1.
other suppliers are same situation does it cover this case?

Comment: It could, if the suppliers are created and registered when instantiating the factory

Comment: i got it. you mean that if supplier is more increase and then the create method has lots of if statement. The Map is able to avoid it. right?

Comment: @dalgoon yep, that's it

Comment: @dalgoon my pleasure :p